# Add event listener to links loaded in webview? (Titanium Mobile)

Tags: titanium-mobile

I am working on a sample app using titanium.
I have created a webview and loaded a local html as shown below

```
var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({ borderWidth:0, paddingRight:10,width:310,top:25, height:210,left:5 });
webview.html = '<div><a href="http://google.com" id="ggle"></a></div>'
```

is it possible for me to add event listener for the anchor tag specified in the html?
if so how? if not please suggest me anyother possible solution.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add your custom event like this:

```
<div><a href="http://google.com" id="ggle" onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent('openLink', {linkUrl: 'http://google.com'});"></a></div>
```

And listen to the event in your app.js file:

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('openLink', function(e){
    Ti.Platform.openURL(e.linkUrl);
});
```

For complete details [Communication Between WebViews and Titanium](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Communication+Between+WebViews+and+Titanium)

Comment: Actually i have used this method, but i am looking for setting "longpress" event for the anchor tag. is that possible?