# Change link behavior in Webview

Tags: javascript, webview, titanium-mobile

I am working in Titanium Mobile. My Question is :

```
 Can I change the behavior of the link present in the webview???
```

i.e. Suppose I have a text : My Name is Burhan. In this text Burhan is a link. So I need when I click on Burhan It should open a window in which I place my Labels etc. Is it possible ???

PS: I want solution just on click of the link and not on click of the webview..
PS: How I can track that the link in webview is clicked .. ??? (I need only this )

Any help ???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: its sad No help Yet :(

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856448/add-event-listener-to-links-loaded-in-webview-titanium-mobile/14872695#14872695

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `Ti.App` EventListeners.

In your WebView you need to provide a tag like

```
<span onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent('url', {information: 'thatcanbeuseful', like: 'anUrl'});">Your Name</span>
```

Then you need to provide a global event listener:

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('url', function(e){
    // open a window or someting or open an URL with:
    Ti.Platform.openURL(e.anUrl); // from passed object
});
```